# Is posible to call api from an container to another in docker environment by container_name:port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker.

I have one service and other service need call the service in docker environment. I wonder if it is posible to call other service by container name like that:

http://container1:port

```
services:
  service-a:
    image: service.a
    container_name: service_a
    ports:
      - '5005:5000'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - 'CONSUL_ENABLED=true'

  service-b:
    image: service.b
    container_name: service_b
    ports:
      - '5004:5000'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - 'CONSUL_ENABLED=true'

networks:
    mynetwork:
        name: aaa-network
```

can Service-a call to service b by: http://service_b:port ?

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) documents this: both `service-a` and the `container_name:` override `service_a` are valid hostnames, between containers, on the same network.  I'd generally remove the `container_name:` options, and delete all of the `networks:` setup to use the `default` network Compose provides for you.

Comment: Dont understand why down vote my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL **postgres://db:5432** and start using the Postgres database.

[`Networking in compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: service a can call service by by name of service? right

Comment: Each container can call other container by container name.

Comment: I have a conatiner A, name of service is: service-a and name of container is: service_a. so I want to register the service with consul, filed adress i need to put service_a or b?

Comment: I've no experience with consul so I can't help here.